# Filtering gdb's backtrace to only display my project's files

Tags: regex, gdb

I want to find where things went wrong in my project when a segfault happens. For this I run `gdb` to produce a backtrace, which I log to a file, then run through a few `sed` commands to remove lines which refer to source files or libraries not in my project. For example, I am not interested in lines like this one:

```
#2  0x00007ffff78bfb3d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

For now I just add filter rules every time a new case crops up (the above being matched by "from /usr/lib/" for example). But I wonder if there would be a better way.

In the cases that I looked at, it seems that my files where the only ones not to start with `/` or `../` in the output. But I am afraid of false positives if I just use this.

A solution less brittle than regexps would also be great.

Comment: With examples for the kind of data you want, regex may actually be quite nice for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own variant of `bt` in Python, using the gdb Python scripting capability.  If you search around you should be able to find one written this way already.  Then, you can modify this `bt` to do whatever you like; in this case, I would suggest white-listing frames based on the "objfile" (gdb lingo for executable or shared library) from which they come.

Comment: Note that while filtering stack traces like Tom described is possible, it is *counterproductive*: you are filtering out *the actual* cause of the crash, making it harder for *you* to understand your bug.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks, that sounds much better than dealing with regexps.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: My experience was to be scrolling through tens of library frames which can each be very long, and not mean anything to me (templates related ones being the worse). The *first* information I want is the last reached point(s) in my files; if that is not enough I then run `gdb` unfiltered.

Comment: FWIW I agree with Employed Russian.  It seems like it will obscure things more than it helps.  However it might be reasonable if you are doing something like fingerprinting stack traces to look for duplicate bugs.